# multiple negative lookahead assertions

Tags: python, regex

I can't figure out how to do multiple lookaround for the life of me. Say I want to match a variable number of numbers following a hash but not if preceded by something or followed by something else. For example I want to match #123 or #12345 in the following. The lookbehinds seem to be fine but the lookaheads do not. I'm out of ideas.

```
matches = ["#123", "This is #12345",
           # But not
           "bad #123", "No match #12345", "This is #123-ubuntu", 
           "This is #123 0x08"]

pat = '(?<!bad )(?<!No match )(#[0-9]+)(?! 0x0)(?!-ubuntu)'

for i in matches:
    print i, re.search(pat, i)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have a look at the captures as well. I bet for the last two strings you will get:

```
#12
```

This is what happens:

The engine checks the two lookbehinds - they don't match, so it continues with the capturing group `#[0-9]+` and matches `#123`. Now it checks the lookaheads. They fail as desired. But now there's backtracking! There is one variable in the pattern and that is the `+`. So the engine discards the last matched character (`3`) and tries again. Now the lookaheads are no problem any more and you get a match. The simplest way to solve this is to add another lookahead that makes sure that you go to the last digit:

```
pat = r'(?<!bad )(?<!No match )(#[0-9]+)(?![0-9])(?! 0x0)(?!-ubuntu)'
```

Note the use of a raw string (the leading `r`) - it doesn't matter in this pattern, but it's generally a good practice, because things get ugly once you start escaping characters.

**EDIT:** If you are using or willing to use the [`regex`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) package instead of `re`, you get possessive quantifiers which suppress backtracking:

```
pat = r'(?<!bad )(?<!No match )(#[0-9]++)(?! 0x0)(?!-ubuntu)'
```

It's up to you which you find more readable or maintainable. The latter will be marginally more efficient, though. (Credits go to nhahtdh for pointing me to the `regex` package.)

Comment: There is no possessive quantifier in Python `re`.

Comment: @nhahtdh just googled and realised and edited that. Thanks anyway! :)

Comment: I believe the `regex` package does have that, though (it supports even more fancier things than possessive quantifier).